# Pyrogram multi account compose

Tags: python, pyrogram

How can I make several accounts do the same thing in pyrogram through compose with one command?

```
import asyncio
from pyrogram import Client, compose


async def main():
    apps = [
        Client("account1"),
        Client("account2"),
        Client("account3")
    ]

    ...

    await compose(apps)


asyncio.run(main())
```